# Determine if a file is in a virtual location from ItemIDList in Delphi 2007

Tags: windows, delphi

I am using the TDropPIDLTarget component from Angus Johnson & Anders Melander's Drag and Drop Component Suite to allow users to add attachments by dragging them in to the form.  The problem I am having is in determining if a file comes from a virtual location (ie: the camera drive or iPhone drive) or from the regular file system.  This is the proof-of-concept code I am using:

```
procedure TfrmForm.dftFileDropDrop(Sender: TObject; ShiftState: TShiftState;
  Point: TPoint; var Effect: Integer);
Var
  I: Integer;
  pItem: PItemIDList;
  Desktop: IShellFolder;
  FileName: TStrRet;
  Attr: UINT;
begin
  If FAILED(SHGetDesktopFolder(Desktop)) Then
    Exit;

  For I := 1 To dftFileDrop.PidlCount - 1 Do
  Begin
    pItem := dftFileDrop.GetAbsoluteFilePidl(I);

    Attr := SFGAO_FileSystem;
    If Succeeded(Desktop.GetAttributesOf(1, pItem, Attr)) Then
    Begin
      If (Attr Or SFGAO_FILESYSTEM) = Attr Then
        Desktop.GetDisplayNameOf(pItem, SHGDN_NORMAL Or SHGDN_FORPARSING, Filename)
      Else
        Desktop.GetDisplayNameOf(pItem, SHGDN_NORMAL Or SHGDN_FORADDRESSBAR, Filename);
      mResults.Lines.Add(Filename.pOleStr);
    End;
  End;
end;
```

The SFGAO_FileSystem constant is supposed to indicate:

> "The specified folders or files are part of the file system (that is,
>   they are files, directories, or root directories). The parsed names of
>   the items can be assumed to be valid Win32 file system paths. These
>   paths can be either UNC or drive-letter based."

This sounds like what I want to use but I can't seem to get the right results from the GetAttributesOf.  Am I doing this the proper way?

Comment: Even file system items can be virtual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `And` operator, not the `Or` operator:

```
If (Attr and SFGAO_FILESYSTEM) <> 0 Then
```

You also need to check for failure before accessing `pOleStr` (and you should not be assuming the value is always in `pOleStr` for that matter, because it might not always be).

You also need to free the `STRRET` content when you are done using it.  Best way to do that is to use one of the `StrRetTo...()` functions, which will handle that for you, as well as analyze the `STRRET.uType` field for you so it knows where and how to extract the string data.

Try something more like this:

```
procedure TfrmForm.dftFileDropDrop(Sender: TObject; ShiftState: TShiftState;
  Point: TPoint; var Effect: Integer);
var
  I: Integer;
  pItem: PItemIDList;
  Desktop: IShellFolder;
  FileName: TStrRet;
  Attr: UINT;
  hr: HRESULT;
  szFileName: array[0..MAX_PATH] of Char;
begin
  If FAILED(SHGetDesktopFolder(Desktop)) Then
    Exit;

  For I := 1 To dftFileDrop.PidlCount - 1 Do
  Begin
    pItem := dftFileDrop.GetAbsoluteFilePidl(I);

    If Succeeded(Desktop.GetAttributesOf(1, pItem, Attr)) Then
    Begin
      If (Attr And SFGAO_FILESYSTEM) <> 0 Then
        hr := Desktop.GetDisplayNameOf(pItem, SHGDN_NORMAL Or SHGDN_FORPARSING, Filename)
      Else
        hr := Desktop.GetDisplayNameOf(pItem, SHGDN_NORMAL Or SHGDN_FORADDRESSBAR, Filename);
      If Succeeded(hr) then
      Begin
        if Succeeded(StrRetToBuf(@Filename, pItem, szFileName, MAX_PATH)) then
          mResults.Lines.Add(szFileName);
      End;
    End;
  End;
End;
```

Comment: Thanks again for your help!  I found that the whole thing was moot though because I could just change the GetDisplayNameOf options to "SHGDN_NORMAL Or SHGN_FORPARSING Or SHGDN_FORADDRESSBAR" and I would get the proper file name displayed regardless of whether it was in a virtual location or not.  I didn't realize I needed to release the StrRet object though, so thanks for that as well.